# optimize weighted sum of sigmoid with sum of sigmoid constraint

Tags: convex-analysis, exponential-function, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, non-convex-optimization

I have a non-convex constraint optimization problem to find its approximate solutions:

First define a parameterized function $$g(s_i) = g(s_i;\mathbf{x})= \operatorname{sigmoid}(x_0 + x_1 \cdot s_i) \cdot x_2 + x_3$$, where $\mathbf{x} = (x_0, x_1, x_2, x_3)$ is the parameters to optimize.

The values $0\leq s_i \leq 1$ comes from known and fixed data. The sigmoid function is defined as: $\operatorname{sigmoid}(x) = \frac{1}{1 + e^{-x}}$.

We also have $1 \leq i \leq n$, where $n$ is a constant value, and $C_{sum}$ is a constant that satisfies $0 < C_{sum} < n$.

The optimization problem is:

minimize:
$$f(x) = -\sum_i s_i \cdot g(s_i)$$
constraints: 
$$\sum_ig(s_i) = \mathit{C_{sum}}$$

$$x_1 > 0$$

$$x_2 > 0$$

$$0 \leq g(s_i) \leq 1$$

we are trying to find the value for $\mathbf{x}$ that minimizes $f(x)$

We can assume there are less than 100 $s_i$ in the data: $1\leq i \leq 100$.

Also, any approximate solution is welcome.

Comment: Thanks, I re-formatted my problem description @joriki

Comment: It is still very strange as written: first, $\log s_i$ can be carried out, so we just need to maximize $\sum_i\log g(s_i)$. Second, the AM-GM immediately implies that we should take $x_1=0$ and just choose $x_0$ appropriately. There must be a misprint somewhere, but I'll abstain from guessing where it really is.

Comment: @fedja You are right, I did make a mistake, the original objective does not have the $\log$ operator and there are 2 more constraints: $x_1$ must greater than 0 and $g(s_i)$ in [0,1]. These two problems are not the same.

Comment: Just to make sure I am understanding correctly: You are trying to find $x_0, x_1$ that minimize $-\sum_{i}^{ }\frac{s_{i}}{1+e^{-\left(x_{0}+x_{1}s_{i}\right)}}$ for given $s_i$?

Comment: @VVejalla Yes, and I am trying to make sure given $x_0$ and $x_1$, $g(s_i)$ is an increasing function of $s_i$.

Comment: Then it looks like there is no minimum and the infimum is approached as you send $x_1$ to $+\infty$ and choose $x_0$ from the constraint on the sum. That's, probably, still not what you expect, so, please, check the formulation again :-)

Comment: @fedja Sorry for the back and forth of the problem description. I re-write the first constraint,$\sum_ig(s_i) = \mathit{C_{sum}} < n$, I think the problem with setting $x_1$ to $+\infty$ is that the first constraint will not be satisfied?

Comment: It will be if you choose $x_0$ appropriately (it will tend to $-\infty$). Actually for any $x_1$, you can find a unique $x_0$ such that $\sum_i g_i=C_{sum}$, so my answer stands for the original version. With $x_2,x_3$, I have to think a bit more :-)

Comment: @fedja Yeah that actually solved my problem;). I am actually trying to find the best function $g(s)$ that minimizes the objective. The optimal function is the step function which is approximated by set $x_2$ to $+\infty$. But a step function is not acceptable for my real world problem. Therefore this problem do lack an additional constraint. Maybe I need an additional constraint on sigmoid slope "width". Your comment helps:) You can paste this to answer and I will accept it. Thanks a lot!